# Limit second and third sql if no insert

Tags: php, mysql

I got on my php script

```
$result1 = mysql_query("insert ignore into...this....
$result2 = mysql_query("insert into...that....
$result3 = mysql_query("insert ignore...again
```

those all are different queries.

when first query tries to insert, and if it has duplicate record, it does not enter this.

well I dont want to run second and third query, if first query did not enter anything.

How do I prevent 2 and 3 query running if first did not enter anything? in PHP please.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a transaction:

```
mysql_query("begin");
$result1 = mysql_query("insert ignore into...this....");
if (mysql_affected_rows() > 0) {
    $result2 = mysql_query("insert into...that....");
    $result3 = mysql_query("insert ignore...again");
    mysql_query("commit");
} else {
    mysql_query("rollback");
}
```

EDIT: This will only work if your tables are InnoDB. MyISAM tables do *not* support transactions.

Comment: Warnig: mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not valid MySQL-link resource... thats what I got ;) –

Comment: @Ossi: Ok, I saw a problem that might cause the warning you saw. I updated my answer. Please try it again and let me know if it works.

Comment: I took begin and rollback out, sinco I dont have InnoDB, 
It works now... mysql_affected_rows() works and mysql_affected_rows($result1) did NOT work...and since "Gumbo" did not fix his answer, I will give you the answer. :)

Comment: @Ossi: If you removed begin and rollback, you might as well remove commit as well.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`mysql_affected_rows` function](http://php.net/function.mysql_affected_rows) to get the number of affected rows:

```
$result1 = mysql_query("insert ignore into...this....");
if (mysql_affected_rows($result1) > 0) {
    $result2 = mysql_query("insert into...that....");
    $result3 = mysql_query("insert ignore...again");
}
```

Comment: Warnig: mysql_affected_rows(): supplied argument is not valid MySQL-link resource... thats what I got ;)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot try it out myself right now, but it looks like [mysql_affected_rows()](http://php.net/mysql_affected_rows) may be able to accomplish what you are looking for.